# Java: Connect to MS-Access Database (mdb or mde)

Tags: java, database, ms-access, jdbc, odbc

I am trying to connect to MS-Access using JDBC:ODBC:

```
public boolean connectToAccess(String accessFilePath) {
    //Get connection to database
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc: odbc: driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=" + accessFilePath);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I get the error:
"No suitable driver found for jdbc: odbc: driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=file.mdb"
Why?
Can you suggest another way of reading access files in Java?

Comment: You shoul dremove the spaces after the colon (:) in the url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take those spaces out of the connection string and see if that helps.  I'd also recommend printing the stack trace.

```
public boolean connectToAccess(String accessFilePath) {
    //Get connection to database
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=" + accessFilePath);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The other way to read Access files is using the [Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/) library.

Comment: Jackcess is very useful and easy to integrate.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a DSN for the Access database from odbcad32. Another issue may be, the driver is not installed on your machine or you have insufficient privileges.